# How to wait to multiple async function to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've devloped a class that has few function that run and update data inside of a database.
I want to run 10 threads of my class at a time , and start new run everytime one of them is done (so there always be 10 operations running or less)
How can I accomplish it?

Example of the code:

```
const classobj = require("data.js");
    let class1 = new Data();
    let class2 = new Data();
    ... //(8 more)

    class1.run();
    class2.run();
    ... // (8 more)

    // one one of the class1-10 is done i want it to start again
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know when it's done?

Comment: Each `run` method will need to resolve a promise. You can then chain each one by either awaiting them inside an async function, or using a `.then()` chain. Examples of this are here: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Your title says that you want to wait for multiple async functions to finish - is that true, or do you want to restart each one when they are done?

Comment: so you would like an endless loop of promises running and if one resolves it should run again with 10?  you could go for a recursive `Promise.race()` that tracks its promises. Actually I some where have the code lying around for something in this direction...

Comment: Patrick - I can add a flag that it will return but right now the running is just done and it returns to the scope

Comment: @victor F i believe you are right , what I want to do is to restart each once its done

Comment: @fubar how can i track which promise is resolved with promise race?

Comment: I have 2 arrays in a namespace `const recSpace = {proms:[], startingPositions:[]}` where initially `startingPositions` is a deep-copy of `proms` and I let the promise resolve its index at creation so that I search for the promise in `startingPositions` and `proms.indexOf(promise)` to find it on the `proms` array. Then just splice it out and start over again

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function call itself when the promise resolves

```js
const randomDelay = () => (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 2) * 1000

const fakePromise = id => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`class ${id} finished work`)
  res()
}, randomDelay()))

class MyClass {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }
      
  run = () => {
    console.log(`class ${this.id} starting work`)
    fakePromise(this.id).then(this.run)
  }
}

// create 3 instances and call .run() on every one
[...new Array(3)]
  .map((_, i) => new MyClass(i + 1))
  .forEach(classInstance => {
    classInstance.run()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Data.run` function returns a Promise, you could do something like this:

```js
const classobj = require("data.js");

const restartingPromise = (promise) => {
  promise().then(() => {
    restartingPromise();
  });
};

let class1 = new Data();
let class2 = new Data();
... //(8 more)

restartingPromise(class1.run);
restartingPromise(class2.run);
...
```